# How do I add a space after each comma in the string?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

how do I change a string (e.g. abc,def,hij) and add a space after each , (e.g. abc, def, hij)
this is the code:

```
        const { songs } = player.getQueue(message.guild.id);
        message.channel.send(`Queue: ${songs}`)
```

the `const { songs }` just gets a list of songs from a queue and if you send it as is, it comes out like abc,def,hij,etc so this is ware I would like to add a space after the , how do I do that?

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I am betting that you have an array and not a string base on comments you made.

Comment: So Eclipse..... did you get your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments, you have an array, not a string. An array does not have a replace method, hence the error you are seeing with the other answers. So use the Array method `join()` which will allow you to format your string the way you want it when it is displayed to the user.

```js
var songs = ['a','b','c'];
console.log(`${songs} vs ${songs.join(", ")}`)
```

Comment: I see someone did not agree it is an array. lol As the comment said `: songs.replace is not a function` which means it is not a string since strings have a replace function. Arrays do not have a replace function. When you do `${songs}` with an array it is really ``${songs.toString()}` which produces the string the OP sees. So all the answers are wrong because it is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Just use JavaScript String replaceAll() and replace `,` with `,`

```
const { songs } = player.getQueue(message.guild.id);
songs.replaceAll(",",", ");
message.channel.send(`Queue: ${songs}`)
```

Or

```
songs = songs.replace(/,/g, ", ");
```

Comment: hopefully there is only one comma. Your solution will fail with more than one.

Comment: Yeah, replaceAll will work I forgot. Thanks

Comment: it says TypeError: songs.replace is not a function

Comment: That means the songs variable will be null or undefined or not a string. Check you are getting string or what.

Answer (score 0):

```js
songs.replace(/,/g, ', ')
```

```js
songs.split(',').join(', ')
```

Try one of those

Answer (score 0):

```
// replace const with let
let { songs } = player.getQueue(message.guild.id);
songs = songs.replace(/,/g, ", ");
message.channel.send(`Queue: ${songs}`);
```

Comment: You should add more details to your answer to explain why this works.